# IP Port Redirection

Tags: port, redirect

I have a silverlight->server communication system up that uses port 4530 among others.  I've used no-ip.org to redirect traffic to my home server.  Is there anyway to use no-ip (or is there another service like it?) to allow me to ping off an ip at port 4530 etc, and send it to my dynamic ip?